# Swiftmailer (Symfony2) Error on first mail attempt

Tags: php, symfony, email, swiftmailer

I've been attempting to debug an issue with new emails in the queue returning an error on first attempt to send. Error is:

```
exception 'Swift_TransportException' with message 'Expected response code 250 but got code "", with message ""`
```

The system is using SMTP to connect to Amazon SES over port 587 and is using `spool: { type: memory }`. Our SES can currently send 20 emails per second, much higher than the system is trying to send.

Any help appreciated. I can't track problem to any email template as it seems to be on arbitrary messages, which eventually do send.

Comment: any small chance that there is a code issue, which occasionally tries to send to an 'empty address'   as in,   an empty string as the TO adress ?

Comment: I had the same error message each time i tried to send an email with an attachment. If attached file isn't readable or accessable - i had this error

Comment: @Sam - sadly no, it's all entity controlled with assorted emails.

Comment: @V-Light - system doesn't have any attachments but good information, thanks!